# Use getElementById in Alert

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
<form method="GET">
<input type="text" class="form" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name!" id="name">
<input type="submit" onclick="return clicked();" value="I'm ready!">
</form>
<script>
function clicked() {
 return confirm('Hiya,');
}
var email = document.getElementById('name').value;
</script>
```

I've had a search around, but I cannot find **any single topic** which matches my question. On the return confirmation where it currently just says Hiya, I would like it to then also include the name which the user entered into the text input.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```html
<form method="GET">
  <input type="text" class="form" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name!" id="name">
  <input type="submit" onclick="return clicked();" value="I'm ready!">
</form>
<script>
  function clicked() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;


    return confirm('Hiya,' + name);
  }

  var email = document.getElementById('name').value;
</script>
```

Comment: How would I then add text after + name?

Comment: Add another +, for example return confirm('Hiya,' + name + ' how are you ?');

Comment: Thanks! JavaScript seems a lot more simpler than PHP

Comment: `<input type = "text" value = "abc" id="text" oninput  ="alert("document.getElementById("text").value") />` This does not work

Comment: @Suray Jain, you may want to ask a different question. The following should work: `<input type = "text" value = "abc" id="text" oninput ="alert(document.getElementById('text').value)">`

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
function clicked() {
    // Here we select the html element with id name and
    // we read it's value.
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;

    // Then my simply concatenating the Hiya with the above value, name
    // we show to the confirm value the message we want.
    return confirm('Hiya,'+name);
}
```

```js
function clicked() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    return confirm('Hiya, '+name);
}
```

```html
<form method="GET">
<input type="text" class="form" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name!" id="name">
<input type="submit" onclick="return clicked();" value="I'm ready!">
</form>
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @JugglingBob please try to run the code snippet and let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I've created a jsfiddle for this example. http://jsfiddle.net/wb4njsrk/

Comment: Code–only answers aren't helpful. You should explain the OP's issue and why your answer fixes it.

Comment: @RobG I agree with you 100%. However, in this specific case, I think that it's pretty clear what is going on. We just select an html element based on its id and the we read it's value.

Comment: If it was "pretty clear", the OP wouldn't have asked the question. Answers are also intended for anyone coming across the question, not just the OP.

Comment: @RobG I say so, because I noticed this `var email = document.getElementById('name').value;` Ok, I will add it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value in the call:

```
<input name="name" ...>
<input type="button" onclick="return clicked(this.form.inputName.value);">
```

where *inputName* is the name of the input, and in the function:

```
function clicked(value) {
 return confirm('Hiya, ' + value);
}
```

However, since you named the input *name*, it attempts to get the form's name, not the name control so rename the control to, say, *userName*, then:

```
<input name="userName" ...>
<input type="button" onclick="return clicked(this.form.userName.value);">
```